# How to scale div to fit Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am making a blog and need for the posts to be displayed in an iframe in the content div (because I don't want to deal with messy code), I need the content div to scale vertically to fit the entire iframe, I have searched for about an hour but nothing has worked, the iframe always stays at the default size.

The blog is here if you want the source - [Blog](http://tomvaliant.co.nf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
html, body, div.page, div.content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also: iFrames are evil. You should stay away from them if possible.

Comment: That iframe is bigger but only scaled to the viewport, not the actual height of the iframe page.